# angularjs http.patch partial model

Tags: angularjs

I'm probably groping in a glass of water...

I have a data source like this in my controller

```
$scope.data = { name: John, lastname: Doh, age: 31 }
```

In my view i have a form to **edit only name**

```
<input type=text ng-model="data.name">
```

Now, on click i would like to send only the name to a specific service, but if I do `http.patch('myapi/path',data)` i send all the model data, also lastname and age...

Ho can i fix to send **only name**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `$scope.data` to be an object with 3 keys `name`, `lastnam` and `age`. Then, you are using the same object to perform a http patch. If you only wish to send the new name, you can try this

```
http.patch('myapi/path',{name: data.name})
```

Comment: Sure it works. I wondered if there was a method that does not provide to rewrite all the values ​​manually. (my real form is about 20 fields)

Comment: HTTP PATCH is to make changes to existing resource. So, you should filter the object properties before sending the patch request. With a number of properties, this can be less manageable, maybe you could have a function that does a diff to calculate what has changed and returns an object with only the diff properties